# build ggplot composite iteratively

Tags: r, ggplot2, iteration

I would like to generate plots iteratively using ggplot.

Imagine that I generate and plot one data frame ...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

x <- seq(0, 4 * pi, 0.1)
n <- length(x)
y1 <- 0.5 * runif(n) + sin(x)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y1)
df1m <- melt( df1, id="x")
p1 <- ggplot( data=df1m, aes(x=x,y=value)) + geom_point(color="blue")
p1
```

... and then some time later generate and plot a second dataframe ...

```
y2 <- 0.5 * runif(n) + cos(x) - sin(x)
df2 <- data.frame(x,y2)
df2m <- melt( df2, id="x")
p2 <- ggplot( data=df2m, aes(x=x,y=value)) + geom_point(color="red")
p2
```

... but how to plot the two overlapping? The following gives and error:

```
p1 + p2
```

There are plenty of examples of how to do this if df1 and df2 are available at the same time and I’m sure that I could store the individual dataframes, but ideally I would like to be able to build a graph as data become available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a second layer to the same plot

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=df1m, (aes(x=x,y=value)), color="blue")

p1 + geom_point(data=df2m, aes(x=x,y=value), color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: A direct and helpful answer. Thank you!